# How to prevent WinUI 3 NavigationView from navigating subpages first when navigating backwards

Tags: c#, navigation, winui-3, navigationview

I have used the WinUI Template Studio to generate the solution.

Visual Studio 2022

The NavigationView in WinUI 3 allows you for navigating between peers and pages. One problem I discovered is having a left navigation with multiple parent pages and each page having multiple children.  If I navigate from parent -> child -> parent and then click the back button, the child is loaded into the current parent instead of navigating back to the original parent.  I'm sure I've messed something up but I am learning the navigation hierarchy.

Example:
Home (Parent) -> Team Page (Child) -> Settings (Parent)

To navigate from Home to Team I am using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(TeamPage))` which works.

```cs
private void SettingsCard_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var effect = new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo()
    {
        Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight
    };

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(TeamPage), null, effect);
}
```

The Page is configured in PageService:

```cs
public PageService()
{
    Configure<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    Configure<ContentGridViewModel, ContentGridPage>();
    Configure<ContentGridDetailViewModel, ContentGridDetailPage>();
    Configure<ListDetailsViewModel, ListDetailsPage>();
    Configure<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
    Configure<TeamViewModel, TeamPage>();
}
```

Is `Frame.Navigate` the correct way to navigate when using the NavigateService provided by the template?

I have reviewed most of the documentation for the:

Frame: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3

Navigation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigation-basics

Comment: For more details about custom back navigation behavior, you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation#guidelines-for-custom-back-navigation-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to help. I'm a bit intermediate, but I've struggled with NavigationView as well.

Basically what's happening with the NavigationView is you are updating the content frame.

Here's a basic XAML:

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavigationMenu" Loaded="NavigationMenu_Loaded" SelectionChanged="NavigationMenu_SelectionChanged">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Your Icon" Content="Text You See" Tag="Your tag" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Your Icon" Content="Text You See" Tag="Your tag" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Your Icon" Content="Text You See" Tag="Your tag" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
```

Here is the C# code to switch pages with the NavigationView:

```
private void NavigationMenu_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourChoice));
}

private void NavigationMenu_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
    {
        // Handle settings here
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

        switch (item.Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "Your tag":
                contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Your Choice));
                break;
            case "Your tag":
                contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Your Choice));
                break;
            case "Your tag":
                contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Your Choice));
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

The switch statement basically says, "Switch == 'Your tag'".

Then the different tags have a line of code that will be used.

```
contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourChoice));
```

That line of code works because YourChoice or Page1 or Home or whatever name you have chosen is a class. Each page of your app is a class.

The child menu should just be for UI and design sake. It shouldn't change how you code your navigation, to the best of my knowledge.

I would try adding more cases to the switch statement for each of your child objects in your menu and treat it as if they're all parent objects. See if that works.

You're doing it a little differently. My example here is basically just how a NavigationView does its job. I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: The problem is navigating backwards.  I have one Frame in the ShellPage which has a NavigationView that has two main items (MainPage, SettingsPage).  From MainPage I have a button that navigates to TeamPage.

If I go from MainPage to TeamPage then TeamPage to SettingsPage, upon clicking back button, SettingsPage will go to TeamPage. Clicking back again will go MainPage.

What should happen is when clicking the back button from SettingsPage, it'd go back to MainPage with the TeamPage loaded.

Should I put another frame in the MainPage along with another instance of a NavigationService?

Comment: That, I’m not sure about. I have never tried to build anything like that before. Is the main issue not being able to click back from settings?

Comment: No, the back button works.  The problem is when clicking back, the TeamPage is being shown in the SettingsPage instead of navigating back to the MainPage and showing the TeamPage as a child.  I think I may have figured it out but doing some testing.

Answer (score 0):

`Frame.Navigate()` and `Frame.GoBack()` should work. This is a basic sample of navigation.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="NavigationExample.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NavigationExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <NavigationView
        BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested"
        IsBackEnabled="True"
        ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="Page A"
                Tag="NavigationExample.PageA">
                <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                    <NavigationViewItem
                        Content="Page A-1"
                        Tag="NavigationExample.PageA1" />
                </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
            </NavigationViewItem>

            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="Page B"
                Tag="NavigationExample.PageB">
                <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                    <NavigationViewItem
                        Content="Page B-1"
                        Tag="NavigationExample.PageB1" />
                </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
            </NavigationViewItem>

        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
    </NavigationView>

</Page>
```

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace NavigationExample;

public sealed partial class ShellPage : Page
{
    public ShellPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked is true)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            return;
        }

        if (args.InvokedItemContainer is NavigationViewItem item &&
            item.Tag is string itemTag &&
            Type.GetType(itemTag) is Type pageType)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(pageType);
        }
    }

    private void NavigationView_BackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ContentFrame.CanGoBack is true)
        {
            ContentFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think I misunderstood your question. It seems that by *child* you mean a child page inside each page.

**ShellPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="NavigationExample.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NavigationExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <NavigationView
        BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested"
        IsBackEnabled="True"
        ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="Page A"
                Tag="NavigationExample.PageA" />
            <NavigationViewItem
                Content="Page B"
                Tag="NavigationExample.PageB" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="MainContentFrame" />
    </NavigationView>

</Page>
```

**ShellPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace NavigationExample;

public sealed partial class ShellPage : Page
{
    public ShellPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked is true)
        {
            MainContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            return;
        }

        if (args.InvokedItemContainer is NavigationViewItem item &&
            item.Tag is string itemTag &&
            Type.GetType(itemTag) is Type pageType)
        {
            MainContentFrame.Navigate(pageType);
        }
    }

    private void NavigationView_BackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (MainContentFrame.CanGoBack is true)
        {
            MainContentFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**PageA.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="NavigationExample.PageA"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NavigationExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    NavigationCacheMode="Required"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*">
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            Text="Page A" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Click="GoToA1Button_Click"
            Content="Go to A-1" />
        <Frame
            x:Name="PageAContentFrame"
            Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

**PageA.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace NavigationExample;

public sealed partial class PageA : Page
{
    public PageA()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GoToA1Button_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PageAContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageA1));
    }
}
```

And the same goes for `PageB`.

Also note that you need to set

```xml
NavigationCacheMode="Required"
```

on pages that you want to be cached. If not, pages will be re-instantiated on each navigation.